# Some questions about Docker Image

Tags: docker

I am very very new to Docker and trying to really wrap my head around the concept and also struggling a little bit. While I have not created any image yet but my team is moving to Docker and I do have very fundamental questions. Let me  start with what I understand

- I can create an Image of my application which can consist of OS version, Web server configuration and Applicaton binaries
- However what I do not understand is that there are far more things involved in n-tier application and I have a lot of questions which I am struggling to find answers for. i just wanted to post some of them here and see if some of them can be clarified.

  1. As I just mentioned above an n-tier application has far more things involved than my Binaries and web server settings. If I have multiple layers(Binaries) for my application say one for services and one for MVC client then do I need an image per layer?)
  2. What happens to .config files? One thing that confused me a lot is that it is mentioned that you can use the same image for testing and prod. Then something has to be different across these environments right? Would that `something` be config files? if yes then why it is not mentioned anywhere?
  3. What happens to DB? Do we spin up another image for DB?

I am hope I am not very far off on my assumptions.